# Google Calendar API Production Launching questions

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am building a chatbot using FreshDesk that will connect to Google Calendar, so I

1. go to Google Console API and create a project
2. add the google calendar API service to the project
3. get the credentials (OAuth client ID)
4. Configure the OAuth consent screen, adding sensitive scope (edit, view, delete)
5. develop my own program which will provide the API to book room using google calendar API.

It still fine here, everything works fine in my local computer. Until I tried to deploy to the server on AWS.

The problem I encountered:

According to the sample code from Google calendar API document (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/dotnet)

When I trigger the API at the first time in my local computer through Postman, Chrome will pop-up automatically and display the consent screen and a file
"Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user" will be generated after I clicked confirm in the screen.

But the consent screen did not pop out after I deploy to AWS server. I need to copy the Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user in my local computer to the AWS server. Is it a proper way to do that? And the file will somehow disappear.. then all of my API is broken without this auth file.. What is the best way to deploy my program to production?

Comment: Do you want this single user? Or do you want users to be able to login to their accounts? Please edit your question and include your code.  i suspect you are using the wrong flow

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want only my API to access the google calendar, so I think it is the single user? My chatbot will call my API to add/edit/remove the google calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to have a few issues here. First off GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is designed for installed applications.  It opens the consent screen on the machine its running on.  So if its running on AWS then its going to try to open the consent screen on AWS which means you the user can not see the consent screen.   The way around this is to run your code once then FileDatastore will store your credentials in the Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user file on your machine.

```
 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

your code will then read from Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user and load the refresh token when ever it needs to.

The issues you are going to have is that there will be no way for your code to request that you authorize it again if the Refresh token expires.  Refresh toekns can expire but its rare after the application has been set to prodcution in Google cloud console.

## service account

You may want to consider using a service account if you use a service account you will need a google workspace account to set up domain wide delegation and the service account will only be able to access a calendar on the workspace domain.

The nice thing about service accounts is that they are pre authorized though domain wide delegation which means you wont need to workie about the refresh token, verifying the app, or the consent screen.